# Proving a set is infinite from 2 statements

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove/disprove the following statement:
If S ⊂ R and S^0 is not the empty set, then S is an infinite set.
I'm pretty sure this is true but I'm not sure how to prove it.
 Using the first part of the question, the information I have is that all elements of S are in R (which is an infinite set) and that S^0 which is the set of interior points is not empty which means it has at least one point in it who's ε-neighbourhood is fully contained in S.
 Any ideas on how to start this?

Comment: You already started it. Call the point $x$. What numbers are in that $\varepsilon$-neighborhood?

Comment: @Joe [x-ε,x+ε] is the closed interval of numbers contained in its neighbourhood

Comment: An ε-neighbourhood is an open interval

Comment: I don't know how @lhf responded to your comment in exactly 1 second, but since, as lhf said, the interval is open, those end points actually are not in the neighborhood, but everything between them is. How many numbers is that?

Comment: so the interval is (x-ε,x+ε)? how does this help me prove that it is an infinite set?

Comment: Well, I assumed that the proof allows you to take for granted that between any two distinct real numbers there are infinitely many real numbers (infinitely many rational numbers too, by the way). If not, then you can prove that (for real numbers) by defining an infinite sequence of midpoints.

Comment: @Joe wait so the interval being (x-ε,x+ε) already proves it because both of them are distinct real numbers and therefore there are infinitely many real numbers in between them?

Comment: $(x-ε,x+ε)$ contains $x+ε/{2n}$ for all $n = 1,2,3,\dots$